# Crop based on aspect ratio

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, aspect-ratio

I have been using this command to crop "portrait" aspect ratio photos.

```c
magick in*.png -resize x1080 -gravity center -extent 640 out.png
```

I would like to use a similar command on a mixed group of photos, such that

- "portrait" photos are cropped to `640x1080`
- "landscape" photos are cropped to `1280x1080`

Is this possible with a "one liner"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IMv7

```c
-extent '%[fx: w>h ? 1280 : 640]'
```

[Crop with specific aspect ratio](http://multipole.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=22863#p96872)